# Change Color Of Bootstrap Vue Collapsed Navbar Icon

Tags: vue.js, navbar, bootstrap-vue, hamburger-menu

I have integrated Bootstrap Vue into my project and am having a hard time customizing it.
Specifically, I am talking about the [Navbar component](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar).

I have read the documentation and saw that I can apply a variant to the navbar that will define the color of the whole navbar.

Thing is, I didn't provide a variant to the navbar (and don't want to) and when it collapses, the collapsed menu icon (hamburger menu icon) is black and is not visible due to the background color of my website.

I have inspected the DOM of the website and used the following CSS rules and selectors:

- `.navbar-toggle`
- `.navbar-toggler`
- `.navbar-toggler-icon`

With each of them I tried to apply the rule:

```
color: white !important;
```

but this had no result.

I have looked online and in SO, but found nothing that addresses this scenario.

Navbar open:
[image: Navbar]

Navbar collapsed:
[image: Collapsed]

Obviously, I can change the background color of my website, but I prefer not to do that as I do not want to change the look and feel of the website just because of a minor issue (and I want to be able to know how to overcome this).

[Link to code](https://github.com/TomerPacific/resume-reviewer/blob/master/src/components/AppNav.vue)

Comment: You should provide some code.

I assume you have a problem with scoped styles.

Comment: When using scoped styles, the scoping only applies to the **root element** of child components.  You need to use the Vue Loader [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) in scoped styles to target the innards of child components.

Comment: @IvanKlochkov - my style is *NOT* scoped in *ANY* component of my Vue application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this scenario by using the following selector:

```
.navbar-toggler > .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-color: white; 
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

@Ivan Klochkov pointed me in the right direction, but I had to mess a bit with the correct selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code - `.navbar-toggle` and `.navbar-toggler` are just plain `div`'s, so `color` prop would affect only text color.

If you are trying to change icon color - it is an inline background svg. you can only override it with your own file.
[image]

Comment: But if I am using the Bootstrap Vue library, I cannot override it... Any suggestions?

Comment: You can by defining a more specific css selector. Something like ``button.navbar-toggler > span.navbar-toggler-icon``